# VNet integrated FunctionApp throws an Error: A connection attempt failed [...] (management.azure.com:443)

Tags: networking, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, vnet

I set up a function app (running on S1 ASP, and yes, App Settings include WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET 1) that executes MS Graph API calls which works perfectly fine without vNet configuration/integration.
Now after I set up vNet integration for my function app and only allow access to it's storage account via selected networks (the very subnet the function app is integrated to) and I reexecute my function, I get a warning that turns into an error:

`WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (management.azure.com:443)'`

`ERROR: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (management.azure.com:443) Exception : Type : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException TargetSite : Name : MoveNext DeclaringType : System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectToTcpHostAsync>d__98, System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03e5f7f21d50a6a MemberType : Method Module : System.Net.Http.dll Message : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [...]`

I obviously tried googling the error messages but could not find anything that helped me. By the way, I did not encounter this problem in another tenant, where I was able to create my own vNet. This problem occured, when using the vNet provided by my organization. Which has a similar configuration but is slightly different. It is set up to use custom dns servers and a Route table activated under "Outbound networking features" this table holds 3 direct routes with next hop type "Internet".

Thank you for your time in advance!

I tried changing the ASP to elastic premium and added app settings to the function app:

```
WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET=1
WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1
```

I also tried to manually establish a connection to azure in the begin{}-block of my function and the profile.ps1 by adding:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription SubscriptionID
```

none of which worked. It seems to be a networking problem

Answer (score 0):

Even the application setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is enabled on the Function level, it is unable to read the storage account files/keys/data.

Within the Virtual Network, the traffic is not being routed properly in your case. You need to setup the [Private Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints) within the Storage Account for the Blob, File, Table, Queue, and Web Level along with the DNS Zone to route the traffic appropriately.

[image]

You can also integrate Service Endpoints to allow the traffic connectivity within the Virtual Network of Function App and its dependency resources located but choosing the [configuration](https://the-tech-guy.in/2022/04/23/private-endpoint-vs-service-endpoint/) of connectivity is either Private or Service Endpoints depends on your requirements.